# Как подсчитать количество комментариев?

Tags: count, orm, kohana, mysql

Всем привет. Вытащил комментарии к данному посту. Количество выводит, но. Если комментов 3, то выводит так 111. Так вот как можно вывести общее число, сложить эти 1. Подскажите. Это форум, поставил на кохану, может есть какой вспомогательный метод (хелпер) у коханы для этого дела?

Answer (score 2):

Я надеюсь, что у вас post has_many comments, т.е. связь 1 ко многим и описана в модели. Если это так, то считается следующим образом:

```
$post = ORM::factory('post');
$comments = $post->comments;
$comments_count = $comments->count_all();
```

или

```
$post = ORM::factory('post');
$comments_count = $post->comments->count_all();
```

Comment: Работает. Но смотри, я считаю коменты по гет запросу
Т.е. на странице где выводится весь пост. А как подсчитать и вывести на главной. Там проверку по гет не сделаеш

Comment: Какие именно комментарии нужно посчитать?

Comment: Есть таблица с темами, есть таблица с комментариями (в ней конечно есть поле с айди темы). Например у темы с айди 3 - 10 комментариев. Переходим на полную страницу темы forum.ru/post/3 делаем проверку по гету и сравнием с таблицей комментов и выводим количество комментов. Проблем нету. А теперь главная страница forum.ru там идет вывод всех тем, количество комментов к каждой теме и т.д. вот делаю проверку как ты выше показал, он считает все коменты с таблицы comments, и например в таблице 17 коментов в общем. И сейчас вместо 111 пишет 171717

Comment: ORM::factory('comment', array('post_id', 3))->count_all();

Comment: А 3 где ты взял) я же не буду это писать сам для каждой темы. Вот смотри я подумал и решил так сделать. К таблице тем я добавил поле count_comments. Теперь после того как пользователь добавил коммент к теме мы это поле обновляем записью, к которой добавляем +1. Но опять же. Когда хочу обновить это поле методом. Update. Орм мне пишет что такого метода нету. Хотя save. Это сохранение. Update перезапись. А delete  удаление. Почему пишет что нету. P.s. попробывал билдером обновить. Так он не обновляет а копирует всю запись

Comment: 3 - Это идентификатор темы.
При выводе списка тем хочется в скобочках иметь количество комментариев? Я правильно понимаю?

Comment: В общем. Но уже все ок. С билдером тупанул просто, не дописал самое главное :) execute